# Face recognition using opencv

Tags: android, opencv, loadlibrary

I am facing problem with opencv in android. I tried a lot searching in google and also try to debug .But not able to figure out the solution. Here is hte logcat file:

```
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load native_sample: findLibrary returned null
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at org.opencv.face.Sample3Native$1.onManagerConnected(Sample3Native.java:83)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:314)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1068)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1085)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
06-27 16:52:41.423: E/AndroidRuntime(6974):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can say that the problem is in loading the native_sample library. But don't have any solution. I am getting error in the following line:

```
// Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
System.loadLibrary("native_sample");
```

Here is my android.mk file :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := native_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And here is my application.mk file:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi
```

Here is my console output:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project Face Recognition_opencv ****

D:\NDK\android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd 
"Compile++ thumb : native_sample <= jni_part.cpp
SharedLibrary  : libnative_sample.so
Install        : libnative_sample.so => libs/armeabi/libnative_sample.so

**** Build Finished ****
```

And my bin file is not generating. That's i am getting error in `"setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);"`  here in "R" .

Comment: Are you sure that your library is compiled successfully? Can you show your `Android.mk` file?

Comment: I have added the android.mk file.

Comment: And are you sure that your C++ code compiled successfully? You can try to build it manually using the command `ndk-build` or build the C++ part using Eclipse.

Comment: From where i can know that c++ code compiled successfull?

Comment: In Eclipse, click on "Build" and have a look at the output in the console...

Comment: I am getting this in my console:
D:\NDK\android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd 
jni/Android.mk:7: ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk'.  Stop.

**** Build Finished ****

Comment: That's your error: your C++ code is never compiled, which explains the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. Edit the question to add this.

Comment: But got another error . It is memory leak error.

Comment: Then you should close this question, validate the answer (if it is correct) and create another question. Try to be clearer this time, and write the output of the console in the question directly!

Answer (score 1):

In your `Android.mk` file, there should be an `include` looking like:

```
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

You need to change it to point to your actual `OpenCV.mk` file (i.e. `$(LOCAL_PATH)` is the path to your `jni` folder, and you need to point to `<your OpenCV4Android folder>/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk`).